# R: Stripping ordinal indicators ('st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th) from character string while keeping the number

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Tried gsub function but it replaces the alphanumeric text rather than just stripping the 'th' part.

```
x <- "11th Rollo Street"
gsub("[0-9]*", "", x)
```

Output needed:

> "11 Rollo Street"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub("(\\d)(st|nd|rd|th)\\b", "\\1", x)
```

**Details:**
`\\\\d`          matches any digit
`(st|nd|rd|th)`  matches any of the suffixes
The parentheses around the groups turn them into "capture groups" that can be recovered with \\1, \\2 etc. So my expression looks for a digit, followed by one of your suffixes and replaces it with just the digit.

Answer (score 0):

Or using `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(x, "(?<=[0-9])(st|nd|rd|th)")
#[1] "11 Rollo Street"
```